# How do I set up Django 1.11 with Python 3.6.1 using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16+

Tags: python, django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

**I'd like to know how to quickly and simply set up Django on Ubuntu**

I have read so much official and user documentation my head is spinning and am not 100% sure where to start.

I'm not an absolute beginner and I have some working knowledge of Django, Python, and Linux Shell Commands (Ubuntu) so the instructions can be quick and to the point.

***Note: I answered my own question below...***

Comment: Did you read the deployment docs, or search Google for any of the many many questions here or tutorials elsewhere on *exactly* this subject?

Comment: Did you read my own answer to my own question before downvoting and accusing ME of not searching and reading documentation?

Answer (score 3):

**Setting up Django 1.11 with Python 3.6.1 using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16+**

> *Note: This does not cover everything you 'could do' - it's meant to get your server up and running with Django as quickly as possible. It should work for later versions, just remember to find the right packages and change versioning accordingly*
>
> You will likely have to change a lot of the paths included so be watchful.

**1. Install Python 3.6 and virtualenv**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6 python3.6-dev
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

> ( Ubuntu Packages https://packages.ubuntu.com/ )

**2. Install Apache2 webserver**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-dev
```

> ( all things apache here https://httpd.apache.org/ )

**3. Make and enter a folder for your project - then build a Virtual Environment in it**

```
mkdir ~/example.com
cd ~/example.com
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 py361ve
```

> ( more about virtual environments here
>   https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/ )

**4. Enter your new Virtual Environment to install packages to it**

```
source py361ve/bin/activate
```

> ( using virtualenv https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/ )

**5. Install Django, mod_wsgi, and any other needed packages**

```
pip install django
pip install mod_wsgi
pip install ...
```

> ( no need for pip3 in virtual environment - pip uses your Virtual Environment python version here )
>
> ( more on pip can be found here
>   https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/  mod_wsgi
>   https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ )

**6. Move an existing project or create a new django project within your ~/example.com folder**

```
django-admin startproject django_project
```

> ( how to build a Django app
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/ )

**7. Edit the wsgi.py file in your Django project folder to add sys paths for your project**

```
import sys 
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

> Additional: sys.path.append(‘/path/to/your/library’)
>
> ( django deployment https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ )

**8. Edit your Django project’s settings.py for your site and set up any additional things you need for your project to work properly.**

> I put my ‘static’ and ‘media’ folders in a separate location from my
>   python code ( within /var/www/example.com/ ) and I think you should
>   too to prevent accidentally making your python code public.
>
> (The VirtualHost example below the instructions should make the setup more
>   clear)
>
> ( Django Settings
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/ )

**9. Run following command and copy output for placement in apache config file**

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

> ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi )

**10. Exit your virtual environment**

```
deactivate
```

> (You can re-enter your virtual environment any time using the source
>   method in step 4)

**11. Navigate to your apache2 configuration folder ( /etc/apache2/ on Ubuntu ) and place the copied text at the bottom of the Apache2 configuration file.**

```
sudo nano apache2.conf
```

> ( more about apache2.conf [ or httpd.conf on some systems ]
>   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html )

**12. Navigate to the /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and create a new conf file for your site. Edit the VirtualHost template (below all instructions) and copy it to this file.**

```
sudo nano example.com.conf
```

> ( VirtualHost examples
>   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html and mod_wsgi
>   daemon mode
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode
>   )

**13. After saving the file, enable this site in Apache**

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

> ( https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DebianLikePlatform )

**14. If you want to enable admin access to your site simply copy the files from your python virtual environment to your aliased static/admin folder**

```
example path: /py361ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin
```

> ( serving admin files
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files
>   )

**15. Any time you update any python or django related script you’ll need to either ‘touch’ the wsgi.py file to reload the daemon process running your site to make it active or restart apache…**

```
touch ~/example.com/my_project/my_project/wsgi.py
        or
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**16. Lastly check that all your folders and files have sufficient group ( usually www-data ) read and write privileges and that the folder your database is in (if using sqlite) has group write privileges.**

> ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions )

**VirtualHost Example Template...**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAdmin info@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

        <Directory /var/www/example.com>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /robots.txt /var/www/example.com/robots.txt
        Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/example.com/favicon.ico
        Alias /static/ /var/www/example.com/static/
        Alias /media/ /var/www/example.com/media/

        <Directory /var/www/example.com/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/example.com/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess example.com  python-home=/home/user_name/example.com/py361ve
        WSGIProcessGroup example.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user_name/example.com/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/user_name/example.com/django_project/django_project>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                         Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*Note: Please edit mistakes and make improvements to the instructions as necessary, but don't try to overcomplicate things*